# MySQL password always prompt to reset password

Tags: mysql, fedora, mariadb

There's something wrong with mysql after i updated it to newer version.
It always prompts to reset my password everytime i boot/re-boot my laptop.

Is there any way to get out of this prompts? Where i can set my password without reset it everytime i open mysqlworkbench, and it's really horrible to change my mysql configuration on my codes everyday.

Here's the screenshot.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Version 5.7?  Check the clock on the server.

Comment: @RickJames yes it's version 5.7, how do i check the clock? i'm sorry for my late respond, i'm having trouble with the internet connection at my region.

Comment: In mysql (if you can get in), `SELECT NOW();`.  I don't know about your OS.  I ask about the version and the clock because of the "password expiration" feature new in 5.7.

Comment: @RickJames alright.. it seems like the password expiration plugin is always on when i restarted the service.. but it already solved now. I'm using this command ALTER USER 'script'@'localhost' PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER. Anyway, thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who troubled by this problem, just reset your password like usual and you can run this command after you logged on to mysql

```
ALTER USER 'user'@'localhost' PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER
```

PS: I'm using MySQL 5.7.9 under Fedora 22